# MATLAB: Removing Zeros in Array collected from Loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

How do I remove the zeros from an array that has been collected from a loop?
I am looping and if distance is less than the store, 5, then enter it into the array, closeHome.  While the array accepts the true values, I also get zeros in the closeHome array.  How do I collect the data into the array without these zeros with the desired output, closeHome =  5.0000    4.1231    2.8284?

```
x = [5 7 4 1 2]'
y = [1 2 3 4 2]'
distance = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2)
store = 5;

for j=1:size(distance)
 if distance(j) <= store
      closeHome(j) = distance(j)
 end       
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your problem is, that you are putting your values on the `j`-th position of `closeHome` which results in `closeHome` always having `size(distance)` elements and all the elements for which the condition is not met will be `0`. You can avoid this by changing the code like this:

```
x = [5 7 4 1 2].';
y = [1 2 3 4 2].';
distance = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2);
store = 5;
closeHome=[];
for j=1:size(distance)
  if distance(j) <= store
    closeHome(end+1)=distance(j);
  end
end
```

Anyway you can also simplify this code a lot using matlabs ability of logical indexing. You can just replace your for loop by this simple line:

```
closeHome=distance(distance<=store);
```

In this case `distance<=store` will create a logical array having 1s for all positions of distance that are smaller than `store` and 0s for all other position. Then indexing distance with this logical array will give you the desired result.
And just for you to know: In matlab programming it's considered a bad practice to use `i` and `j` as variables, because they're representing the imaginary unit. So you might consider changing these and use (e.g) `ii` and `jj` or smth completely different.

Comment: I agree, of course. I just like to correct this particular issue when I see it. :)